# What does the question mark in this codeigniter nginx rewrite means?

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm migrating my codeigniter files from apache to nginx, and looking at the rewrites for nginx. I came across the following rewrite to remove the codeigniter index.php

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}
```

The rewrite **works**. But, I quite don't understand the `/index.php?/` part.

**UPDATE :**

I tried the rewrite **without** the question mark, like `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;`. It works for normal controllers, but breaks when a value is posted to a controller by third parties like fb oauth like `/controller?code=something`.

**My questions**

1) What is the role of the question mark in this rewrite ? Does this make **index.php** optional ?

2) Also, codeigniter does not route url's with question marks, like in a get request. For example, a get request like this

```
http://example.com/controller?code=somecodehere
```

breaks and does not call the controller, but trying to literally call `controller?code=somecodehere`. This routing takes care of that, but I just don't understand how.

Any insights on this rewrite will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a part of regexp but simply a question mark in rewritten url

so

`abc`

becomes:

/index.php **?** /abc

as you should know - `get` parameters in php are passed after question mark sign in url

now codeigniter in `index.php` can read from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and will get `/abc`. From this it can load the proper controller

Comment: so, is it like for every request like `controller` it calls `index.php?/controller` even if there is no get parameter in the url ?

Comment: yes, it simply rewrites `/anything?something` to `/index.php?/anything%3Fsomething` and handles this in `index.php`. No magic after that

Comment: and how get requests for controller dealt in this rewrite ? how something like `/controller?code=something` handled ?

Comment: codeigniter gets this as string in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and takes care of it